# Lumen/Laravel queuing jobs: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: php, sql, laravel, locking, lumen

All of a sudden (there has been no modifications or updates to this live application to my current knowledge) I am getting the following error when trying to queue jobs in Lumen:

> (3/3) QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: **General error: 1205 Lock wait
>   timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction** (SQL: insert into `jobs`
>   (`queue`, `payload`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (helpdocs,
>   {"displayName":"App\Jobs\Helpdocs\FetchUpdateCategories","job":"Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"App\Jobs\Helpdocs\FetchUpdateCategories","command":"O:39:\"App\Jobs\Helpdocs\FetchUpdateCategories\":5:{s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}},
>   0, , 1520427665, 1520427665))

*in Connection.php (line 664)*

It seems like that it does not matter which concrete job is queued.

Excerpt of the relevant PHP code:

```
                case "update-categories": {
                    Queue::pushOn('helpdocs',new FetchUpdateCategories());
                    return "The Jobs has been queued.";
                    break;
                }
                case "articles-to-local": {
                    Queue::pushOn('helpdocs',new FetchRemoteArticles());
                    return "The Job has been queued.";
                    break;
                }
```

What may be the cause for this problem and how to solve it?

Note: If I run the Jobs `handle()` method directly they succeed.

Comment: Log into your database and try `show processlist`, and see if there are any long-running queries sitting there.

Comment: Three running processes:
317 user localhost:xxxxx mydb Sleep 3   NULL 0.000
8675789 user localhost:xxxxx NULL Query 0 init show processlist 0.000
8675791 user localhost:xxxxx NULL Sleep 0   NULL 0.000

Did not know this command what does this tell me?

Comment: It shows the currently running queries on the server. So the issue isn't a stuck query...

Comment: I killed process 317 with Kill 317; and now everything seems to work (at least temporarily)?!

Comment: hope this helps .. [lockfile](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7046) .. >taylorotwell commented on May 17, 2016
The issue is in the query that migrates jobs that have been reserved too long to being available. We have a bunch of workers trying to execute that query simultaneously. We could simply ignore problems with that query and assume another worker is already doing it. I'm curious if even when you get deadlocks your queues keep processing as normal?

Comment: Might be possible ty for all the information. I will monitor if this was a one time problem or if it happens again.